# scrollbar is not enabled in entity framework using bootstrap

Tags: css, entity-framework, twitter-bootstrap

I have created an application in entity framework using bootstrap,but I have the problem that my content goes out of the browser view. Normally the scroll bar is on the right side of the screen, but not in my case. I gave `overflow-y:scroll;` in bootstrap.css file  but that didn't solve the problem.

Does someone know how to enable scroll bar in bootstrap.css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to bootstrap.css:

```
    html{
        overflow-y:scroll !important;
    }
```